# How can I predict or check if an external website (not owned by me) will send me a value for $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']

Tags: php, http, http-headers, http-referer

HElp me to predict or check by pinging or by any other method whether an external website (not owned by me) will send me a value for $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'].
I do not have control from that website(external) to check.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

The HTTP_REFERER is not sent by a website but by the user's browser. A browser should send the referer every time the users follows a link, but you can't trust this information. There are several things that can filter this information such as browser extensions.